# Flutter / Dart FFI existing .so file for Android

Tags: android, flutter, dart, dart-ffi

I'm trying to use a pre-compiled .so file with Flutter/Dart FFI.

I've generated bindings with dart-ffigen, which seems to work without any issues.

I've added the following to the build.gradle file within the `android` block.

```yaml
    externalNativeBuild {
        // Encapsulates your CMake build configurations.
        cmake {
            // Provides a relative path to your CMake build script.
            path "CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)  # for example

find_library( stl_android
             ../ios/Classes/libstl.so )

add_library( stl_android SHARED IMPORTED )
```

I've also tried the cmakelists.txt file that is documented on the FFI page, but that gives an exception related to it not knowing the language of the .so file. I'm assuming that's because it is an compiled library, not sourcecode.

In Dart I use the following code:

```dart
Platform.isAndroid
        ? DynamicLibrary.open('libstl.so')
        : DynamicLibrary.process();
```

But this gives the following exception:

```
Invalid argument(s): Failed to load dynamic library 'libstl.so': dlopen failed: library "libstl.so" not found
```

I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong here, I'm expecting something in the makelist file to be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this issue by using this CMakeLists.txt

```dart
add_library(
        stl_android
        SHARED
        IMPORTED
        GLOBAL
)
set_target_properties(stl_android PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/jniLibs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libstl.so)
```

The .so files need to be added in the following directory:

- `android/app/src/main/jniLibs/arm64-v8a`
- `android/app/src/main/jniLibs/armeabi-v7a`
- `android/app/src/main/jniLibs/x86`
- `android/app/src/main/jniLibs/x86_64`

and any other platform you might want to support.

The .so files need to be compiled for the correct targets of course.

Comment: Is there a similar process for `macos` and `linux` platforms? Is there a way to include a non-platform-specific binary, or would you have to bloat the build with a copy in each directory? How did you arrive at this answer?

Comment: You cannot use .so's for Mac OS as far as I'm aware, you need to compile them to a .a or dylib and add them to Xcode. You might also need .m files for the iOS/Mac OS version. I don't know about Linux.